# Error when install 'e1071' in R on Mac

Tags: r, gcc

[Error shown on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYeOC.png)

```
> install.packages('e1071')
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/e1071_1.6-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 581513 bytes (567 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 567 KB

* installing *source* package ‘e1071’ ...
** package ‘e1071’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... configure: error: cannot 
run C++ compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘e1071’
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/e1071’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘e1071’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've checked on terminal, gcc is installed and updated.
I also tried https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html to download both latest and former versions manually and installed them on R console. The error was still there. 
How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error when using RStudio through Anaconda. I just re-downloaded RStudio from the R website, and now the error has gone away, and e1071 installs just fine.

Comment: Worked for me, but so very strange why it fails when launched from Anaconda.